# HLK Studio crashes at start-up with XamlParseException

Tags: windows, digital-signature

I already found my solution and thought I would share it since I didn't find any answer anywhere.
At start-up, HLK Studio crashes with an System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException error.

It started doing that on multiple machines, and uninstall/reinstall didn't help. So I analyzed what it does with ProcMon and found that before crashing it's reading stuff in the registry.

So I renamed the key and restarted the studio and this time it worked. Solution below.

Answer (score 0):

I renamed the following key and restarted the studio and this time it worked. So if you are having the same issue, just rename/remove this key (it's recreated at start-up) with regedit:

**HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\HCK Studio**